# Ruby - Iterating over and calling an array of methods

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, ruby-block

Lets say I have two methods:

```
def hello
 'hello'
end

def world
 'world'
end
```

Now I want to call these methods in a fashion like this:

```
try_retry{
  hello
}
try_retry{
  world
}
```

assume try_retry is a method that will retry the block of code if an error happens. There are a lot of these methods so is it possible to iterate over the blocks? Something like:

```
array_of_methods = [hello,world]
array_of_methods.each do |method|
  try_retry{
    method
  }
end
```

the problem is the methods get evaluated on this line:

```
array_of_methods = [hello,world]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
array_of_methods = [method(:hello), method(:world)]
```

And you can call them like

```
array_of_methods.each { |m| m.call }
```

Comment: Note: with this answer `method(:hello)` is an object for the method `hello` and does not directly call the method. This is very nice because you have more options as to what to do with the method, but if you are only calling the method, using `send` is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have the methods `hello` and `world`. If you want to call these methods while iterating over them, you can do it as such

```
['hello', 'world'].each do |m|
  send(m)
end
```

Comment: Method names are usually symbols. Besides, you have to call `send` within `try_retry { ... }` to actually solve the OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the origin of this array of method names you might not want to allow private or protected methods to get called so `public_send` will allow for only public methods to be called.

```
array_of_methods = ['hello', 'world']

array_of_methods.each {|m| public_send(m)}
```